# android FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP doesnt clear the stack whic has the same activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

in my application it has function where you can further go below a structure 
so that i will be opening the same activity again and again with different data

Example:

```
MainActivity -> activity1 (1) -> activity1 (2) -> activity1 (3)
```

I have stored this structure in an array 
so if i navigate back to `activity1(1)` by setting the intent flag to `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` it doesn't clear `activity1` (2) , `activity1` (3) from the back stack  ( it still appears on back button press )

Comment: Can you post the Intent code for above?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding two more flags

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
```

Comment: what im trying to do  is store the intents in an array and when i wanted to navigate back to a previous activity i set the flag to clear top and restart the intent so that everything created after that activity will be removed from the back stack , or is there any other way of accessing android (activity) stack

Answer (score 0):

**1. APPROACH 1**

If we are to follow your approach, you can achieve what you want by using @shuvro's answer this way:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Intent> intents = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intents.add(intent);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!intents.isEmpty()) {
            Intent intent = intents.get(0);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the **AndroidManifest.xml** you should add this property on your activity:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

**2. APPROACH 2**

I think this approach is a cleaner one. 
You can create an activity for each screen that extend a BaseActivity where you have the common code. So, when you open the Activity1 (which is the root and should be launched as **singleInstance**) and Activity2 you would open them without any flags. But when you will have to open Activity3, you should add the flags.

**From MainActivity**
Open Activity1:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity1.class);
  startActivity(intent);
```

**From Activity1**
Open Activity2:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**From Activity2**
Open Activity3:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```